# Non-lexicographic sort based on particular column of file which is tab separated

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, sort

`file.txt` is tab separated:

```
RollNo  Names    Class  Subject  Position
101     Anna     V      Maths    Average
102     Bob      V      Maths    Good
103     Charles  VI     Science  Good
104     Darwin   VI     Science  Improve
105     Eva      VII    English  Improve
```

I want to sort the lines so that they appear in the order `Good`, `Average`, `Improve`:

```
RollNo  Names    Class  Subject  Position
102     Bob      V      Maths    Good
103     Charles  VI     Science  Good
101     Anna     V      Maths    Average
104     Darwin   VI     Science  Improve
105     Eva      VII    English  Improve
```

Comment: -k option of sort command is exactly for that, so you should use
sort -k 5 file.txt. Mind also, that If the header line is the part of the file, you may want to skip it to not interfere.

Comment: @Tagwint That would sort `Average` first...

Comment: input is in tab separated format.

Comment: Related: [*How to do custom sorting using unix sort?*](https://superuser.com/questions/489275/how-to-do-custom-sorting-using-unix-sort)

Comment: @Kusalananda, you're right, I overseen the point
Pls ignore my first comment

Comment: @sebasth That's not a dupe. It is however very similar to the question that you mentioned as related.

Comment: @Kusalananda but the highest votes anwser from Gillies explain how you would solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `file.txt`:

```
RollNo  Names    Class  Subject  Position
101     Anna     V      Maths    Average
102     Bob      V      Maths    Good
103     Charles  VI     Science  Good
104     Darwin   VI     Science  Improve
105     Eva      VII    English  Improve
```

Replace the last words on the line with numbers. Sort using these numbers. Then replace these with the original words:

```
$ sed -e 's/Good$/1/' -e 's/Average$/2/' -e 's/Improve$/3/' file.txt | sort -k5n | sed -e 's/1$/Good/' -e 's/2$/Average/' -e 's/3$/Improve/'
RollNo  Names    Class  Subject  Position
102     Bob      V      Maths    Good
103     Charles  VI     Science  Good
101     Anna     V      Maths    Average
104     Darwin   VI     Science  Improve
105     Eva      VII    English  Improve
```

Alternatively, prefix each line by a number depending on the last word on the line and sort on that number. Then remove that first column:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {n=0} $NF=="Good" {n=1} $NF=="Average" {n=2} $NF=="Improve" {n=3} { print n, $0 }' file.txt | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
RollNo  Names    Class  Subject  Position
102     Bob      V      Maths    Good
103     Charles  VI     Science  Good
101     Anna     V      Maths    Average
104     Darwin   VI     Science  Improve
105     Eva      VII    English  Improve
```

Comment: Using your command I tired to do sort based on 4th column which is in the order of Science, English, Maths. I just modified k4n. But I am getting regular sort. 
**sed -e 's/Maths$/1/' -e 's/English$/2/' -e 's/Science$/3/' file.txt | sort -k4n | sed -e 's/1$/Maths/' -e 's/2$/English/' -e 's/3$/Science/'**

Comment: @bioinform Well, yes of course. The command is written to sort the last column. If you want to sort the 4th column, use my `awk` solution instead and change `$NF` to `$4` and the strings to the ones that occur in the 4th column. (`$NF` will be the contents of the last column. In this example, it is equivalent to `$5`).

Answer (score 3):

This snippet:

```
# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input data file $FILE:"
head $FILE

pl " Sort order file:"
head data2

pl " Expected output:"
head $E

pl " Results:"
msort -q -Z -l -n 5,5 -s data2 -c lexicographic $FILE
```

produces:

```
-----
 Input data file data1:
RollNo  Names   Class   Subject Position
101     Anna    V       Maths   Average
102     Bob     V       Maths   Good
103     Charles VI      Science Good
104     Darwin  VI      Science Improve
105     Eva     VII     English Improve

-----
 Sort order file:
Good
Average
Improve

-----
 Expected output:
RollNo  Names   Class   Subject Position
102     Bob     V       Maths   Good
103     Charles VI      Science Good
101     Anna    V       Maths   Average
104     Darwin  VI      Science Improve
105     Eva     VII     English Improve

-----
 Results:
RollNo  Names   Class   Subject Position
102     Bob     V       Maths   Good
103     Charles VI      Science Good
101     Anna    V       Maths   Average
104     Darwin  VI      Science Improve
105     Eva     VII     English Improve
```

by using *msort*, an alternate sorting code found in many repositories.
It is slower that GNU sort, but has a number of additional features that make it useful in many situations. The options here are -Z (copy first line), -l (a line is a record), -q (quiet), -n (key field location), -s (sort order file, one key per line), -c (comparison type).

This was on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
```

Some details for msort:

```
msort   sort records in complex ways (man)
Path    : /usr/bin/msort
Version : 8.53
Type    : ELF64-bitLSBexecutable,x86-64,version1(SYSV ...)
Help    : probably available with -h,--help
Repo    : Debian 8.9 (jessie) 
Home    : http://www.billposer.org/Software/msort.html (pm)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl